# Why there are button areas defined for my Apple Magic Trackpad though xorg's default config disabled them?

Tags: xorg, trackpad

I wanted to configure my Apple Magic Trackpad and came to a point where I realised there were button areas defined in the right top and bottom corner. I tried to disable these by the suggested synclient options RTCornerButton and RBCornerButton with no success.

Checking the system default files in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
I noticed it should not be necessary to manually disable them for Apple products.
These are the trailing lines of /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf:

```
# This option disables software buttons on Apple touchpads.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Disable clickpad buttons on Apple touchpads"
    MatchProduct "Apple|bcm5974"
    MatchDriver "synaptics"
    Option "SoftButtonAreas" "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

Why are these button areas active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the MatchProduct key is interpreted case sensitive. xinput -list gives me

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HID 046a:0023                             id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HID 04d9:1135                             id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Trackpad von apple
```

The trackpad is listed as *Trackpad von apple*. For those who don't know: *von* is a german word. As german is my system language this seems to be the cause my trackpad is listed like that.

Adding *apple* in lower case to /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf does the trick.

```
    MatchProduct "apple|Apple|bcm5974"
```

As I don't want to modify system config files belonging to the root user I configured it by adding the line

```
Option "SoftButtonAreas" "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
```

to my /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/60-magictrackpad.conf, which is the recommended way for individual configuration.

Comment: Trackpads can be renamed (using a Mac). So your advice is not relevant to someone whose trackpad is no longer called "Trackpad von apple". The new name has to be used instead.

Comment: What I was trying to say is the default configuration for the trackpad does not work if your system generates a name that doesn't match the expression for "MatchProduct". Given the above 50-synaptics.conf file I doubt even the driver would be loaded for the trackpad if you rename it... And please tell me why it's relevant that you're using a Mac as we are talking about Ubuntu's X11 configuration files?

Comment: It's relevant because trackpads can be renamed. Maybe you need a Mac to do so, but that hardly matters. You can't put matching names into the xorg file if they fail to match because a particular trackpad has been renamed. So anyone attempting this needs to take that into account.